# PIDTemplate in Wix

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I am working on an installer written in WIX. It defines PIDTemplate as

```
<Property Id="PIDTemplate"><![CDATA[{50}<????????-????????-??????????>]]></Property>
```

The code worked - asking 28 letters and digits, including two hyphens.

However, Microsoft documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx does not mention {50}. What is this used for?

Also the page on MSDN site is quite difficult to understand. It says:

> The alternate digit, %, and alternate
>   alphanumeric characters, ^, ?, and `
>   fields allow custom actions to
>   differentiate between fields in a way
>   that can be controlled by the mask,
>   for example, ^ can be used for fields
>   that should be uppercase.

My PIDKey allows only uppercase letters and digits. Does that meant that I can achieve it by replacing ? with ^?

Answer (score 1):

> However, Microsoft documentation
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx does not mention {50}. What is this
>   used for?

It specifies the maximum length of the edit (50 characters).

> My PIDKey allows only uppercase
>   letters and digits. Does that meant
>   that I can achieve it by replacing ?
>   with ^?

? means digit or character. I'm not sure if ^ supports digits, but you can try using it instead of ?. And to answer your question, yes, it should limit the edit to uppercase characters.